# NullPointerException for WebSphereMBeanServerFactoryBean

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have some Websphere jars on my classpath causing issues for Spring AnnotationMBeanExporter

Can I tell Spring to exclude `org.springframework.jmx.support.WebSphereMBeanServerFactoryBean` or ignore MBeans under `com.ibm` packages?

Full exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'mbeanServer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jmx/JmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.management.MBeanServer]: Factory method 'mbeanServer' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.MBeanServerNotFoundException: Could not access WebSphere's AdminServiceFactory.getMBeanFactory/getMBeanServer method; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration.mbeanExporter(JmxAutoConfiguration.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66ba1cc0.CGLIB$mbeanExporter$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66ba1cc0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$15838c0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66ba1cc0.mbeanExporter(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.management.MBeanServer]: Factory method 'mbeanServer' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.MBeanServerNotFoundException: Could not access WebSphere's AdminServiceFactory.getMBeanFactory/getMBeanServer method; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.MBeanServerNotFoundException: Could not access WebSphere's AdminServiceFactory.getMBeanFactory/getMBeanServer method; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.jmx.support.WebSphereMBeanServerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(WebSphereMBeanServerFactoryBean.java:78)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.MBeanExportConfiguration$SpecificPlatform$2.getMBeanServer(MBeanExportConfiguration.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration.mbeanServer(JmxAutoConfiguration.java:103)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66ba1cc0.CGLIB$mbeanServer$1(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66ba1cc0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$15838c0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66ba1cc0.mbeanServer(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.jmx.support.WebSphereMBeanServerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(WebSphereMBeanServerFactoryBean.java:67)
    ... 70 more
```

spring-boot `1.3.5.RELEASE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the `MBeanServer` yourself, which will disable any attempt to locate the best option according to your environment. I guess the following should work

```
@Bean
public MBeanServer mbeanServer() {
  MBeanServerFactoryBean factory = new MBeanServerFactoryBean();
  factory.setLocateExistingServerIfPossible(true);
  factory.afterPropertiesSet();
  return factory.getObject();
}
```